# Any more concise way to set default values?

Tags: php, variables, variable-assignment, default-value

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the
>   ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1
>   evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

Is there any better or more concise way than following code to set default value of variables?

```
$v = isset($v) ? $v : "default value";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a shorter syntax:

```
isset($v) || $v="default value";
```

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR** - No, that expression can't be made any shorter.

What you want is for the shortened ternary expression to perform an implicit `isset()`. This has been discussed on the [mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/internals@lists.php.net/msg49880.html) and an [`ifsetor` RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/ifsetor) has been created that covers the concept as well.

Since the shortened ternary operator already existed at the time of the above discussion, something like this was [proposed](http://www.mail-archive.com/internals@lists.php.net/msg49934.html) using a non-existent operator `??`:

```
// PROPOSAL ONLY, DOES NOT WORK
$v = $v ?? 'default value';
```

*Assign `'default value'` if `$v` is undefined.*

However, nothing like this has been implemented in the main language to date. Until then, what you have written can't be made any shorter.

This *horrible* construct is shorter, but note that it's **not the same** because it assigns the default value if the variable exists but evaluates to `false`:

```
// DO NOT USE
$v = @$v ?: 'default value';
```

Comment: What if `$v` is already set and it's `''` or `0` or `null` or `false`?

Comment: @jackflash Hence my mention of "horrible construct"

Comment: This is not a good practice. So we can do like this - error_reporting( E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE);
echo $v = $v ?: 'default value'; This is same output as above.

Comment: @SoumyaBiswas I can't choose what is worse.

Comment: @SoumyaBiswas Yes, that's right; the `@` does roughly the same, so the answer is really that it's not (practically) possible to make OP code shorter :)

Comment: Seems that this is my first controversial answer at SO; upvotes == downvotes :)

Answer (score 2):

Just asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086980/php-return-if-isset#comment19481440_14086980) and was pointed here. So in case you use a `key` of an `array`, this might be an improvement

```
function isset_get($array, $key, $default = null) {
    return isset($array[$key]) ? $array[$key] : $default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope. That's the right way if you don't really know whether `$v` is set.

Answer (score 0):

No way.If you use ternary operator.