# PHP return if isset

Tags: php, isset, built-in

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any more concise way to set default values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507779/any-more-concise-way-to-set-default-values)

Is there a built-in php function like the following:

```
function isset_get($array, $key, $default = null) {
    return isset($array[$key]) ? $array[$key] : $default;
}
```

I don't like

```
$my_var = isset($my_array['some Key']) ? $my_array['some Key'] : '';
```

and would prefer

```
$my_var = isset_get($my_array, 'some Key', '');
```

or something similar...

Comment: @SunnyRed you've just made one, use it.

Comment: :) Do you see an advantage in the later style?

Comment: @SunnyRed not really... but for **similar** (not exactly the same) functionality you could use `$my_var = $my_array['key'] || $default;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  In my codebase we have several helpers of this nature.  The names are pretty terrible but since they are frequently used, concision is warranted

`idx($array, $key, $default)`
returns the $default if !isset($array[$key])

`adx($array, $key, $default)` 
like idx, but enforces that $array is actually an array and throws if not.

`edx($array, $key, $default)`
returns the $default if !isset($array[$key]) or empty($array[$key])

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `array_merge`. Merging will overwrite keys of each given array allowing you to override an array of default values with the given values.

```
$defaults = array('some Key' => 'some Default Value');
$input = array('some Key' => 'a new value');
$merged = array_merge($defaults, $input);
$value = $merged['some Key'];
```

This won't work correctly for numeric keys however, so you should ensure you're working with an map instead of a vector.