# php: write isset function which returns value or null

Tags: php, function, null, default-value, isset

I have the following code in numerous places (thousands of places) around my project:

```
$foo = isset($mixed) ? $mixed : null;
```

Where `$mixed` can be anything: array, array element, object, object property, scalar, etc.  For example:

```
$foo = isset($array['element']) ? $array['element'] : null;
$foo = isset($nestedArray['element']['key']) ? $nestedArray['element']['key'] : null;
$foo = isset($object->prop) ? $object->prop : null;
$foo = isset($object->chain->of->props) ? $object->chain->of->props : null;
```

Is there a way to write this repeated logic as a (simple) function?  For example, I tried:

```
function myIsset($mixed)
{
    return isset($mixed) ? $mixed : null;
}
```

The above function looks like it would work, but it does not in practice.  For example, if `$object->prop` does not exist, and I call `myIsset($object->prop))`, then I get fatal error: `Undefined property: Object::$prop` before the function has even been called.

Any ideas on how I would write such a function?  Is it even possible?

I realize some solutions were posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507779/any-more-concise-way-to-set-default-values) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086980/php-return-if-isset), but those solutions are for arrays only.

Comment: I don't think you can do that more efficiently. Instead I would try to reduce the number of times you use it, *thousands* seems far too much. I would guess that whole blocks of variables are either set or not so checking for one could give you the opportunity to set various.

Comment: @jeroen It is a "code smell" if you're having to check this so often everywhere

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I stumbled across the answer to my own question while reading about [php references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php).  My solution is as follows:

```
function issetValueNull(&$mixed)
{
    return (isset($mixed)) ? $mixed : null;
}
```

Calls to this function now look like:

```
$foo = issetValueNull($array['element']);
$foo = issetValueNull($nestedArray['element']['key']);
$foo = issetValueNull($object->prop);
$foo = issetValueNull($object->chain->of->props);
```

Hopefully this helps anyone out there looking for a similar solution.

Answer (score 11):

PHP 7 has a new "Null coalescing operator" which does exactly this. It is a double ?? such as:

```
$foo = $mixed ?? null;
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! This is easy and simple build-in little function.

Answer (score 2):

`isset` is a language construct, not a regular function. Therefore, it can take what would otherwise cause an error, and just return false.

When you call `myIsset($object->prop))`, the evaluation occurs and you get the error.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

This is the same problem as using `typeof nonExistentVariable` in JavaScript. `typeof` is a language construct and will not cause an error.

However, if you try to create a function, you get an error for trying to use an undefined variable.

```
function isDef(val) {
    return typeof val !== 'undefined';
}

console.log( typeof nonExistent !== 'undefined'); // This is OK, returns false
isDef(nonExistent); // Error nonExistent is not defined
```

Answer (score -1):

You could actually just write it like:

```
$foo = $mixed?:null;
```

Comment: No, that would generate a warning if `$mixed` is not set.

Comment: It would generate a Notice. And you have no business having notices or warnings being displayed in a production environment.

Comment: If you're writing code like that, you might as well skip that whole ternary expression as an unset variable evaluates to `NULL`.

Comment: No, just `$foo = $mixed;`. That would result in `$foo === NULL` if `$mixed` is not set.

Comment: Haha, good point ! - that sorta makes this whole question useless.

Answer (score -2):

If you just want to check if it exist do this

```
function myIsset($mixed)
{
    return isset($mixed); // this is a boolean so it will return true or false
}
```

Comment: Why write a function which just returns the result of a global function?  Semantics?

Comment: i agree it is redundant.

Answer (score -2):

```
function f(&$v)
{
    $r = null;

    if (isset($v)) {
        $r = $v;
    }

    return $r;
}
```